# Prime numbers : missing a few ones

Tags: algorithm, primes

**Before flag as duplicate read this :**

**I don't want to know how the others do or what is faster, I want to do it by my self.**

### The problem:

I get a little difference between the calculated prime number and the real one (around 1%).
I can't spot where is the error...

For example :

From 2 to 50 000 :

> > [Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=how%20many%20primes%20from%202%20to%2050000) return 5 132 and my algorithm return 5 182

From 2 to 500 000 :

> > [Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=how%20many%20primes%20from%202%20to%20500000) return 41 537 and my algorithm return 41 665

I assume that I'm wrong and Wolfram|Alpha is right so here is my code :

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QVector>
#include <QDebug>

QVector<int> tabPrime;
bool isPrime(int n)
{
    bool boolIsPrime = true;
    int i = 0;

    while (boolIsPrime && tabPrime.at(i) * tabPrime.at(i) < n)
    {
        if (n % tabPrime.at(i) == 0)
            boolIsPrime = false;
        i++;
    }

    if(boolIsPrime)
        tabPrime.append(n);

    return boolIsPrime;
}


int main()
{
    int numberWanted = 500000;
    tabPrime.append(2);
    tabPrime.append(3);
    for(int i = 4; i < numberWanted; i++)
        isPrime(i);

    qDebug() << "There is" << tabPrime.count() << "primes numbers from 2 to" << numberWanted;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Dweeberly tabPrime is a QVector, what does-it change?

Comment: I think this `tabPrime.at(i) * tabPrime.at(i) < n` should be `tabPrime.at(i) * tabPrime.at(i) <= n`. You are counting prime squares as primes.

Comment: What values does it return that aren't prime? Compare it to http://primes.utm.edu/lists/small/millions/ .  Also, minor optimizations, the for loop in main, increment by 2 (skip even numbers), and only test up to the sqrt of the number.

Comment: Seems like you could have your program output the primes that it finds and check them against a list of primes (a Google search will give you a list). When you find a number that your program says is prime, but isn't in the list, you can use the debugger to figure out where you went wrong.

Comment: @ypercube right, this is better but not perfect, I now get `41538` instead of `41357`

Comment: @RBarryYoung I add 2 and 3 to it

Comment: @MichaelT this is micro-optimisation, this will not change the result. FYI sqrt(n) is lower that tabPrime.at(i) ^ tabPrime.at(i).

Comment: You copied it wrong from Wolfram Alpha, it's 41537. The off-by-one error is probably caused by `i < numberWanted` instead of `i <= numberWanted`

Comment: A different bit - you may enjoy implementing the [Sieve of Sundaram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Sundaram) instead.

Comment: @MichaelT as said, I want it to be done by myself :)

Comment: @Samoth implementing a known algorithm isn't *not* doing it by yourself (you're doing a form of the Sieve of Eratosthenes currently).    There are other sieves, some of them are more applicable to certain coding approaches.  The "sieve to" form is one that works very nicely with the Sundaram approach.

Comment: @MichaelT when I mean by myself, I mean that I went from brute force to this

Comment: well looks like its solved so just a hint change your main for loop go from 5 and increment by 2 to avoid check even numbers which is pointless...

Comment: @Spektre I can also add manually the first 1000 primes ;)

Comment: hehe yes ... if you saw my isprime routine you would probably LOL me out :-) but its fast (combine few Sieve of Eratosthenes some buffering methods, memoization ,etc...)

Comment: @MichaelT The "Sieve of Sundaram" is just the sieve of Erathostenes with a minor optimization, IMHO it doesn't deserve a proper name.  And the algorithm above does trial division, it is not a sieve.

Comment: @starblue did you vote me down? If so, could you tell me why :)

Comment: @starblue To an extent, all sieves are the same with different optimizations.  There are some aspects of Sundaram that are nice when doing functional programing in that it becomes a filter and map that doesn't rely upon building the list of primes as one goes to do do the filtering.

Comment: @MichaelT No, that's wrong. The sieve of Atkin is completely different.  The "Sieve of Sundaram" is just the sieve of Erathostenes with wheel factorization w.r.t. 2.  Possibly even worse than Erathostenes, because you don't restrict the filtering to primes. In the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Sundaram) it is unclear whether the restriction to primes is one of the optimizations.

Comment: @MichaelT If you do filtering in a functional language then most likely you are doing trial division, not sieving.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this:

```
tabPrime.at(i) * tabPrime.at(i) < n
```

should be:

```
tabPrime.at(i) * tabPrime.at(i) <= n
```

You are counting prime squares as primes.

The square root of 50000 is 223.6... and there are 48 primes from 2 to 223. You also append 3 twice (the loop should start at 4, not 3). 48+1 = 49 and that explains the difference of 49 between the correct results (5133 for up to 50000) and yours (5182).

Comment: This is the right answer but also note that his values from Wolfram are for the number of primes between 2 and 50,000 excluding 2, so that this program will give one more prime (2) than the numbers he gives above.

Comment: @A.E.Drew Ah thnx, I didn't check those numbers. But now I'm confused a bit. The difference between the code and the correct value is 49 and I can't explain that!

Comment: I think 9 is not appended twice in the original code. We have an extra 48 squares of primes appended and an extra 3, making a difference of 49.

Comment: Yes, I figured that out, thank you. The 9 is checked only once. Answer corrected.

Answer (score 2):

Your method sometimes adds full squares of largest primes found so far. Replace

```
boolIsPrime && tabPrime.at(i) * tabPrime.at(i) < n
```

with

```
boolIsPrime && tabPrime.at(i) * tabPrime.at(i) <= n
```

Here is a [demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/EU0lVR).